# How can I prove that there is only one set of prime factors for a number?

Tags: prime-numbers, prime-factorization

How can you prove that a number cannot have more than one set of prime factors?

You would know that $15$, for example, has $2$ prime factors $3$ and $5$.

you can easily know that these are the only prime factors because you can try dividing $15$ all the primes numbers less than $15$, and you wouldn't find any other number. But how can you know that for any number $n$, there cannot be more than one set of prime factors?

Another way to state this(after trying to prove my theory, I ended up with this)

if you have a number $A$ and a prime $p$ both not divisible by prime $q$, how can you prove that $A\cdot p$ is not divisble by $q$?

Comment: See [Fundamental theorem of arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic).

Comment: What you are speaking of is called [the fundamental theorem of arithmetic][1]. As the name hints, the theorem is not trivial to prove.

  [1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic

Answer (score -1):

$A×p$ won't be divisible by $q$, because $p$ isn't...  I saw this the other day, i believe it's called Euclid's lemma...

The *fundamental theorem of arithmetic*  answers your question though...

Answer (score -2):

Well, the 2 numbers are prime, say $a$, $b$.  Then our product is $ab$.  Evidently, it has only 2 prime factors, since factors are only $a$ and $b$.

Comment: But how do you know the factors are unique? (That's what OP is asking, after all)

Comment: The number ab where a and b are primes has evidently 2 factors only(excluding 1 and itself)

Comment: Without already knowing the fundamental theorem of arithmetic (which OP clearly doesn't know), how do you know that?

Comment: Factoring.  That way is rather simple

Comment: But how do you know factoring is unique? How do you know that if $p_1p_2=q_1q_2$ where $p_i,q_i$ are prime, then $\{p_1,p_2\}=\{q_1,q_2\}$?

Comment: The problem is that your “evidently” is actually a rather deep theorem. And on the set of numbers of the form 4K+1 it isn’t true. 441 = 21*21 = 9*49.